# Solve PDE via Mathematica

Tags: numerics

[image]

Here is my code,but it did not work, how to solve this equation with numerical method. I donnot know the problem

```
cs = 1/Sqrt[3];`pde = {2 v/\[Xi][v] == (1/(1 - v^2)^(
  1/2))^2 (1 - 
   v  \[Xi][v]) (((\[Xi][v] - v)/(1 - \[Xi][v]  v))^2 cs^-2 - 
   1) (D[\[Xi][v], v])^-1};bc = {(\[Xi][v] /. v -> 0) == cs};solu = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, \[Xi], {v, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$Version
(*"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"*)

ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

cs = 1/Sqrt[3]; 

pde = {2 v/\[Xi][v] == (1/(1 - v^2)^(1/2))^2 (1 - 
  v \[Xi][v]) (((\[Xi][v] - v)/(1 - \[Xi][v] v))^2 cs^-2 - 
  1) (D[\[Xi][v], v])^-1}; 

bc = {(\[Xi][v] /. v -> 10^-10) == cs};

solu = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, \[Xi], {v, 10^-10, 1 - 10^-10}]
Plot[\[Xi][v] /. solu, {v, 10^-10, 1 - 10^-10},PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: thank you, but it does not work

Comment: Works for me in 13 on Windows 10.

Comment: Works for v12.2.0 Win7-x64. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co6wc.png)

Comment: I try it again, it works, thank you very much!